# N-Dependency injection in C - better way than linker-defined arrays?

Tags: c, design-patterns, gcc, dependency-injection, linker

Given a *library module*, in the following called `Runner`, which resides as a *reusable component* (no recompilation required, i.e. static link library) in the *app partition* of the architecture, not the *main partition*. Note that it only contains `main()` for demo purposes.

Given a *set* (order irrelevant) of other modules / objects called `Callable`s, i.e. `Callable1`, `Callable2` and `Callable3`, which also reside as *reusable components* in the *app partition*.

`Runner` has a runtime dependency on the `Callable`s in that `Runner` needs to know each and every of these `Callable`s in order to get data from them (access a structure) or have them perform an operation (call a function).

`Runner` shall not have a compile dependency on the `Callable`s. Instead the dependencies shall be injected via the linker into a fictive module `Callables`.
The concept shall be usable not only in a *hosted environment* but also a *freestanding environment*. Therefore, loader-based mechanisms like loading the `Callable`s as shared objects at runtime cannot be used.

### How can one inject the dependencies using the linker?

My *working solution* is by letting the `Callable`s define pointers in a dedicated section, in this case named `Callables`, which the linker would collect so that the `Runner` can access it, gaining the necessary information at link time.

#### Callable.h

```
#ifndef CALLABLE_H
#define CALLABLE_H
typedef void (*Callable)(void);
#endif
```

#### Callables.h

```
#ifndef CALLABLES_H
#define CALLABLES_H
#include "Callable.h"
extern Callable Callables_start[];
extern Callable Callables_end[];
#endif
```

#### Runner.c

```
#include "Callables.h"
void Runner_run(void) {
    for (Callable *callables = Callables_start; callables < Callables_end; callables++)
        (*callables)();
}
int main(void) {
    Runner_run();
    return 0;
}
```

#### Callable1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Callable.h"
static void Callable1_call(void) {
    printf("Callable 1\n");
}
static Callable thisCallable __attribute__((section("Callables"))) = &Callable1_call;
```

`Callable2.c` and `Callable3.c` look the same except for a different message in `printf()`.

#### Callables.ld

```
PROVIDE(Callables_start = LOADADDR(Callables));
PROVIDE(Callables_end = Callables_start + SIZEOF(Callables));
```

#### Makefile

```
CFLAGS+=--std=c99
callables:=Callable1 Callable2 Callable3
.PHONY: all
all: Runner

Runner: Callables.ld Runner.o $(addsuffix .o, $(callables))
```

#### Output

```
$ make -s && ./Runner
Callable 1
Callable 2
Callable 3
```

The output shows that the solution works, but I'm not satisfied with the solution. **What are alternative, preferably better ways to inject dependencies using the linker** than the solution that I've found?

#### Note

The environment is *GCC / ld* on *x86_64* with `-ffreestanding`, but I'm very much interested in solutions that are less toolchain-specific / more portable than the solution which I've found so far.

Comment: What is a *partition?* What is an *architecture?* I'm not sure what you mean with these words.

Comment: *architecture* is the overall high-level design. According to Robert C. Martin and others, it consists of two partitions, the *app*lication partition and the *main partition*. In the *app*, all rules like following the *SOLID and package principles* apply. The *main* is usually small, sticks the stuff from the *app* together, and we're maybe not always as strict about replacing `switch`-`case`-statements with polymorphisms and avoiding dependency cycles as usual. Most importantly, the *main* depends on the *app*, but the *app* not on the *main*.