# How does the C preprocessor go from a macro to a struct definition

Tags: c, reflection, macros

As I was searching for a way to do reflection in C, I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31908340/6784916.

In his answer, he refers to the metaresc library and he shows an example how to use it:

```
TYPEDEF_STRUCT (point_t,
                double x,
                double y
                );

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
  point_t point = {
    .x = M_PI,
    .y = M_E,
  };

  ...
}
```

TYPEDEF_STRUCT is defined on line 237 of https://github.com/alexanderchuranov/Metaresc/blob/master/src/metaresc.h

I tried extracting the source of the macro but I'm not sure if I missed something because it's so complex.

```
#define TYPEDEF_STRUCT(...) P00_TYPEDEF (STRUCT, __VA_ARGS__)

#ifndef MR_MODE
#define MR_MODE_UNDEFINED
#define MR_MODE PROTO
#endif
#include <mr_protos.h>
#ifdef MR_MODE_UNDEFINED
#undef MR_MODE_UNDEFINED
#undef MR_MODE
#endif

#define MR_IS_MR_MODE_EQ_MR_MODE 0
#define P00_TYPEDEF(...)                        \
  MR_IF_ELSE (MR_PASTE2 (MR_IS_MR_MODE_EQ_, MR_MODE))           \
  (P00_TYPEDEF_MODE (MR_MODE, __VA_ARGS__))             \
  (P00_TYPEDEF_MODE (PROTO, __VA_ARGS__) P00_TYPEDEF_MODE (DESC, __VA_ARGS__))

#define MR_IGNORE(...)
#define MR_IDENT(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define MR_IF_ELSE_CASE_0(...) __VA_ARGS__ MR_IGNORE
#define MR_IF_ELSE_CASE_1(...) MR_IDENT
#define MR_IF_ELSE(...) MR_PASTE2 (MR_IF_ELSE_CASE_, MR_IS_EQ_0 (__VA_ARGS__))

#define MR_PASTE2(...) MR_PASTE2_ (__VA_ARGS__)
#define MR_PASTE2_(_0, _1) _0 ## _1

#define MR_IS_0_EQ_0 ,
#define MR_IS_EQ_0_CASE_011 ,

#define MR_GET_SECOND(_0, ...) __VA_ARGS__
#define MR_IS_EQ_0(...) MR_IS_EQ_0_ (__VA_ARGS__) /* evaluate arguments */
#define MR_IS_EQ_0_(...) MR_IS_EQ_0__ ((__VA_ARGS__), (MR_PASTE2 (MR_IS_0_EQ_, __VA_ARGS__)))
#define MR_IS_EQ_0__(ARGS, ARGS_EQ_0)                   \
  MR_HAS_COMMA (MR_PASTE4 (MR_IS_EQ_0_CASE_,                \
               /* test if there is just one argument, eventually a zero */ \
               MR_HAS_COMMA ARGS,               \
               /* test if MR_IS_0_EQ_ together with the argument adds a comma */ \
               MR_HAS_COMMA ARGS_EQ_0,          \
               /* test that there is nothing after comma */ \
               MR_IS_EMPTY (MR_GET_SECOND ARGS_EQ_0)))

#define P00_TYPEDEF_MODE(P00_MODE, P00_TYPE, ...)           \
  P00_TYPEDEF_MODE_ (P00_MODE, P00_TYPE,                \
             ATTRIBUTES (P00_GET_ATTRIBUTES (__VA_ARGS__)), \
             P00_GET_NON_ATTRIBUTES (__VA_ARGS__))
#define P00_TYPEDEF_MODE_(...) P00_TYPEDEF_MODE__ (__VA_ARGS__)
#define P00_TYPEDEF_MODE__(P00_MODE, P00_TYPE, ATTR_META_RES, ...)  \

#define P00_GET_ATTRIBUTES(...) MR_FOREACH (P00_EXTRACT_ATTRIBUTES, __VA_ARGS__)
#define P00_GET_NON_ATTRIBUTES(...) MR_FOREACH (P00_EXTRACT_NON_ATTRIBUTES, __VA_ARGS__)

#define MR_FOREACH(X, ...) MR_PASTE2 (MR_FOREACH, MR_NARG (__VA_ARGS__)) (X, __VA_ARGS__)
#define MR_FOR(NAME, N, OP, FUNC, ...) MR_PASTE2 (MR_FOR, N) (NAME, OP, FUNC, __VA_ARGS__)

#define P00_TYPEDEF_ATTR_STRUCT TYPEDEF_ATTR
#define P00_TYPEDEF_ATTR_UNION TYPEDEF_ATTR
#define P00_TYPEDEF_ATTR_ENUM TYPEDEF_ATTR
#define P00_TYPEDEF_ATTR_CHAR_ARRAY(P00_MODE, P00_TYPE, ATTR_META_RES, P00_TYPE_NAME, SIZE, ...) MR_PASTE2 (MR_TYPEDEF_CHAR_ARRAY_, P00_MODE) (P00_TYPE_NAME, SIZE, MR_PASTE2 (P00_REMOVE_, ATTR_META_RES), __VA_ARGS__)
#define P00_TYPEDEF_ATTR_FUNC(P00_MODE, P00_TYPE, ATTR_META_RES, RET_TYPE, P00_TYPE_NAME, ARGS, ...) MR_PASTE2 (MR_TYPEDEF_FUNC_, P00_MODE) (RET_TYPE, P00_TYPE_NAME, ARGS, MR_PASTE2 (P00_REMOVE_, ATTR_META_RES), __VA_ARGS__)

#define P00_UNFOLD(PREFIX, P00_TYPE, P00_MODE, ...) MR_PASTE4 (PREFIX, P00_TYPE, _, P00_MODE) (__VA_ARGS__)

#define TYPEDEF_ATTR(P00_MODE, P00_TYPE, ATTR_META_RES, P00_TYPE_NAME, ...) \
  P00_UNFOLD (MR_TYPEDEF_, P00_TYPE, P00_MODE, P00_TYPE_NAME, MR_PASTE2 (P00_GET_FIRST_, ATTR_META_RES)) \
  MR_FOR ((P00_MODE, P00_TYPE_NAME), MR_NARG (__VA_ARGS__), MR_SER, MR_PASTE3 (P00_, P00_TYPE, _HANDLER), __VA_ARGS__) \
  P00_UNFOLD (MR_END_, P00_TYPE, P00_MODE, P00_TYPE_NAME, MR_PASTE2 (P00_GET_OTHER_, ATTR_META_RES))

# define P00_IS_ATTRIBUTES_EQ_ATTRIBUTES(...) 0 /* help macro for ATTRIBUTES test IF clause */
#define P00_REMOVE_ATTRIBUTES(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define P00_GET_FIRST_ATTRIBUTES(FIRST, ...) FIRST /* extract typedef attributes */
#define P00_GET_OTHER_ATTRIBUTES(FIRST, ...) __VA_ARGS__ /* extract typedef meta information */
```

All I want to know is how can a macro call such as

```
TYPEDEF_STRUCT (point_t,
                    double x,
                    double y
                );
```

expand to that

```
typedef struct point_t {
          double x;
          double y;
} point_t;
```

Comment: Have a look at the macro definition.

Comment: @tadman I did but I don't understand it, I'm asking for an explanation of how it works.

Comment: It may help to show the macro in question.

Comment: @tadman  I added a link to the macro source. I would have pasted it in my question but the macro is like a rabbit hole.

Comment: You should taylor the reference code from [here](https://github.com/alexanderchuranov/Metaresc/blob/master/src/metaresc.h). Selecting all the involved macros might be a pain, but without it it is impossible to provide an answer. What if the linked project is removed?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I tried.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? For example GCC can show you the preprocessed source with the option `-E`. But granted, this *does not show how* to get to the result. I think you need to "play" preprocessor and do all expansions step-by-step manually.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you want to decouple headers from the rest of the library. Probably first 700 lines of metaresc.h are used in TYPEDEF_STRUCT, so you will need most of this file. Even though it will not help you, just because result of the macro is typedef + meta-data required for serialization. Serialization functions are implemented in the library, so there is no sense to decouple meta-data generation from the code that uses this meta-data.

You could run example through preprocessor and evaluate outcome. This will give you and idea what do I mean as meta-data.

If you are really interested in understanding of TYPEDEF_STRUCT macro implementation details, then get ready for 100+ layers of nested macros. As a first exercises you could start here https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/detect-empty-macro-arguments/ and continue with other macro tricks from https://p99.gforge.inria.fr/